# Exported movieclip assets are not scaling properly on createjs stage

Tags: javascript, movieclip, createjs

I'm creating a dynamic widget using canvas, createjs and assets from Flash. There's a certain movieclip in Flash which I export to js, and using createjs I render this movieclip into the canvas. It has to be responsive, so the canvas can be any size- to which through additional js code I scale the exported movieclip to fit.

The scaling function is simple. This is CoffeeScript code but it's pretty straight forward:

```
    @movieclip = new lib.MyWidget()
    @stage.addChild(@movieclip)
    box = @movieclip.getBounds()
    w_ratio = $canvas.width() / box.width
    h_ratio = $canvas.height() / box.height
    @movieclip.scaleX = @movieclip.scaleY = Math.min(w_ratio, h_ratio)
    @movieclip.x = (@stage.canvas.width) / 2
    @movieclip.y = (@stage.canvas.height) / 2
```

The result though is always off. The movieclip does not scale properly, it ends up too big or too small. It's as if the original `getBounds` measurement is wrong. I also tried `getTransformedBounds` but it doesn't seem to differ.

Any idea what's causing this? The original movieclip animation has a few layers in it, some of it masked... I'm still trying to see if it's something to do with it

Libraries in place: createjs, movieclipjs, tweenjs, jquery.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure this out. The fact that easeljs movieclips don't have `width` and `height` properties made it even more confusing. But it turned out to be something completely different: it's the Flash asset export settings.

When publishing, make sure to enable "multiframe bounds". The output JS file is significantly bigger, but that's ok in my case.

> Multi-frame bounds—If checked, timeline symbols will include a “frameBounds” property containing an array
>   of Rectangles corresponding to the bounds of each frame in the timeline. Note: Selecting this option may result
>   in increased publishing times

http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/flash/pdfs/html_extension_faq_ie.pdf